# double free error found when try to cleanup client port info

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, epoll

I have an existing client and server code running in Linux machine. Server is implemented using epoll. The client runs two thread and creates two client ports, via these two ports the client connects to a single listening port on the server. There are two global similar hash maps which keep information about the peer client and its port respectively on the server based on some key.  When the client is closed, we have to clean up the hash map on the server and delete peer client IP and port info. For which I have written a cleanup code. This cleanup code should clean both hash map data. However, when I kill the client side using control+C, I observe a    **"double free or corruption (out)"**   error. It seems code cleanup is not working properly and instead of cleaning up both the hashes individually it cleans the same map twice but not sure why and how. Can anyone help me to figure this out?

To keep code snippet simple, I have removed unnecessary variable declaration etc. full code can be found here. https://github.com/o-ran-sc/ric-plt-e2/blob/master/RIC-E2-TERMINATION/sctpThread.cpp

```
int main(const int argc, char **argv) 
{
    // start epoll
    sctpParams.epoll_fd = epoll_create1(0);
    if (sctpParams.epoll_fd == -1) {
        mdclog_write(MDCLOG_ERR, "failed to open epoll descriptor");
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    // there are two global map one for keeping client port1 information and other for cleint's port2 information
    sctpParams.GlobalMap1 = new mapWrapper();      // defnition of this is not shown intentially to code snippet simple          
    sctpParams.GlobalMap2 = new mapWrapper();      
    std::vector<std::thread> threads(num_cpus);

    num_cpus = 3;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num_cpus; i++) {
        threads[i] = std::thread(listener, &sctpParams);

        cpu_set_t cpuset;
        CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
        CPU_SET(i, &cpuset);
        int rc = pthread_setaffinity_np(threads[i].native_handle(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
        if (rc != 0) {
            mdclog_write(MDCLOG_ERR, "Error calling pthread_setaffinity_np: %d", rc);
        }
    }
}

void listener(sctp_params_t *params) 
{    
    // some other variables and code are here which are not shown just to show code simple
    // .....
    // .....
    
    auto *events = (struct epoll_event *) calloc(MAXEVENTS, sizeof(struct epoll_event));
    while (true) {
        if (mdclog_level_get() >= MDCLOG_DEBUG) {
            mdclog_write(MDCLOG_DEBUG, "Start EPOLL Wait. Timeout = %d", params->epollTimeOut);
        }
        auto numOfEvents = epoll_wait(params->epoll_fd, events, MAXEVENTS, params->epollTimeOut);

        if (numOfEvents == 0) { // time out
            continue;
        } else if (numOfEvents < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {

                continue;
            }
            
            if(events)
            {
                free(events);
                events = nullptr;
            }
            return;          
        }
        for (auto i = 0; i < numOfEvents; i++) {
            if ((events[i].events & EPOLLERR) || (events[i].events & EPOLLHUP)) {
                handlepoll_error(events[i], message, rmrMessageBuffer, params);
            } else if (events[i].events & EPOLLOUT) {
                handleEinprogressMessages(events[i], message, rmrMessageBuffer, params);
            } else if (params->listenFD == events[i].data.fd) {

                // new connection is requested from RAN start build connection
                while (true) {
                    struct sockaddr in_addr {};
                    socklen_t in_len;
                    char hostBuff[NI_MAXHOST];
                    char portBuff[NI_MAXSERV];

                    in_len = sizeof(in_addr);
                    auto *peerInfo = (ConnectedCU_t *)calloc(1, sizeof(ConnectedCU_t));
                    if(peerInfo == nullptr){
                        mdclog_write(MDCLOG_ERR, "calloc failed");
                        break;
                    }
                    peerInfo->sctpParams = params;
                    peerInfo->fileDescriptor = accept(params->listenFD, &in_addr, &in_len);                    
                    if (peerInfo->fileDescriptor == -1) {                        
                        if ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) {
                            /* We have processed all incoming connections. */
                            if(peerInfo)
                                free(peerInfo);
                                peerInfo = nullptr;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            if(peerInfo)
                                free(peerInfo);
                                peerInfo = nullptr;                            
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (setSocketNoBlocking(peerInfo->fileDescriptor) == -1) {                        
                        close(peerInfo->fileDescriptor);
                        if(peerInfo)
                            free(peerInfo);
                            peerInfo = nullptr;
                        break;
                      
                    }
                    struct sctp_event_subscribe sctpevents;
                    memset( (void *)&sctpevents, 0, sizeof(sctpevents) );
                    sctpevents.sctp_data_io_event = 1;
                    setsockopt(peerInfo->fileDescriptor, SOL_SCTP, SCTP_EVENTS,(const void *)&sctpevents, sizeof(sctpevents) );

                    auto  ans = getnameinfo(&in_addr, in_len, peerInfo->hostName, NI_MAXHOST, peerInfo->portNumber, NI_MAXSERV, (unsigned )((unsigned int)NI_NUMERICHOST | (unsigned int)NI_NUMERICSERV));
                    if (ans < 0) {                        
                        close(peerInfo->fileDescriptor);
                        if(peerInfo)
                            free(peerInfo);
                            peerInfo = nullptr;
                        break;
                    }
                    peerInfo->isConnected = false;
                    peerInfo->gotSetup = false;
                    if (addToEpoll(params->epoll_fd,
                                   peerInfo,
                                   (EPOLLIN | EPOLLET),
                                   params->GlobalMap1, nullptr,
                                   0) != 0) {
                        if(peerInfo)
                            free(peerInfo);
                            peerInfo = nullptr;
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            } else if (params->rmrListenFd == events[i].data.fd) {                     
                mdclog_write(MDCLOG_ERR, "Error handling Xapp message");                
            } else if (params->inotifyFD == events[i].data.fd) {                
                handleConfigChange(params);
            } else {
                receiveDataFromSctp(&events[i],
                                    params->GlobalMap1,
                                    params->GlobalMap2,
                                    num_of_SCTP_messages,
                                    rmrMessageBuffer,
                                    message.message.time);
            }            
        }
    }
}



int receiveDataFromSctp(struct epoll_event *events,
                        Sctp_Map_t *GlobalMap1,
                        Sctp_Map_t *GlobalMap2,
                        int &numOfMessages,
                        RmrMessagesBuffer_t &rmrMessageBuffer,
                        struct timespec &ts) 
{
    /* We have data on the fd waiting to be read. Read and display it.
     * We must read whatever data is available completely, as we are running
     * in edge-triggered mode and won't get a notification again for the same data. */
    ReportingMessages_t message {};
    auto done = 0;
    struct sctp_sndrcvinfo sndrcvinfo;
    int flags;
    int streamId;

    // get the identity of the interface
    if (events->data.ptr != nullptr){
        message.peerInfo = (ConnectedCU_t *)events->data.ptr;
    } 


    while (true) {      
        if (message.message.asnLength < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                continue;
            }
            /* If errno == EAGAIN, that means we have read all
               data. So goReportingMessages_t back to the main loop. */
            if (errno != EAGAIN) {                
                done = 1;
            } else if (loglevel >= MDCLOG_DEBUG) {
                mdclog_write(MDCLOG_DEBUG, "EAGAIN - descriptor = %d", message.peerInfo->fileDescriptor);
            }
            break;
        } else if (message.message.asnLength == 0) {
            /* End of file. The remote has closed the connection. */            
                mdclog_write(MDCLOG_INFO, "END of File. The remote has closed the connection. - descriptor = %d", message.peerInfo->fileDescriptor);           
            done = 1;
            break;
        }              
        numOfMessages++;
    }

    if (done) 
    {
        mdclog_write(MDCLOG_INFO, "Closed connection - descriptor = %d", message.peerInfo->fileDescriptor);        
        /* Closing descriptor make epoll remove it from the set of descriptors which are monitored. */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_lock);
        if (fcntl(message.peerInfo->fileDescriptor, F_GETFD) != -1) {
            mdclog_write(MDCLOG_DEBUG, "Closing connection - descriptor = %d", message.peerInfo->fileDescriptor);
            close(message.peerInfo->fileDescriptor);
            // client has pressed the control + C to close its connection. We want to cleanup both the client port and   ---> issue
            // its data kept in GlobalMap1 and GlobalMap2. however I get error   double free or corruption (out)
            cleanHashEntry((ConnectedCU_t *) events->data.ptr, GlobalMap1);
            cleanHashEntry((ConnectedCU_t *) events->data.ptr, GlobalMap2);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_lock);
    }

    return 0;
}

void cleanHashEntry(ConnectedCU_t *val, Sctp_Map_t *m) 
{   
    if(val != nullptr)
    {
        char *dummy;
        auto port = (uint16_t) strtol(val->portNumber, &dummy, 10);
        char searchBuff[2048]{};

        snprintf(searchBuff, sizeof searchBuff, "host:%s:%d", val->hostName, port);       
        if(m->find(searchBuff))
        {            
            m->erase(searchBuff);
        }

        if(m->find(val->enodbName))
        {            
            m->erase(val->enodbName);
        }

        if(val) {
        free(val);
        val = nullptr;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Debugger, do you use it?

Comment: but there is no crash at all. it just says double free or corruption (out). I hope i will not get backtrack. please let me know if i am wrong

Comment: `MALLOC_CHECK_=3 gdb ./yourprogram` (see also `man mallopt`). There are also debugging tools that are not gdb, such as valgrind and address sanitizer.